# Get values from json file

Tags: perl, sed, awk, grep, tr

Want to get the values from json files:

Example:

```
{"ipaddr":"10.1.1.2","hostname":"host2","role":"http","status":"active"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.1.3","hostname":"host3","role":"sql","status":"active"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.1.4","hostname":"host4","role":"quad","status":"active"},
```

Expected:

```
10.1.1.2 host2 http active
10.1.1.3 host3 sql active
10.1.1.4 host4 quad active
```

I try with:

```
grep -Po '(?<=ipaddr\")[^\"]+'
```

But was able to get only ":", like result and it's only one when I start to get something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -Po ':"\K[^"]*' file
```

will print out all values that you need. but the format is not what you are expecting, because of the `-o` each matching will sit in one line. what you could try is:

```
 grep -Po ':"\K[^"]*' file|xargs -n4
```

test:

```
kent$  grep -Po ':"\K[^"]*' f|axrgs -n4           
10.1.1.2 host2 http active
10.1.1.3 host3 sql active
10.1.1.4 host4 quad active
```

with **awk** you could do extracting and formatting in one shot:

```
awk -F'":"|","|"}' '{print $2,$4,$6,$8}' file
```

if you have many fields, you could write a loop, just print the fields with EVEN idx.

test with your file:

```
kent$  awk -F'":"|","|"}' '{print $2,$4,$6,$8}' f
10.1.1.2 host2 http active
10.1.1.3 host3 sql active
10.1.1.4 host4 quad active
```

Comment: assuming the JSON is on a single line.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen the answer is based on the example in question.

Comment: I get that, but the question is about parsing JSON. It doesn't mean the JSON will always be on the same line.

Comment: @Kent, how can include additional separator like "|"

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I agree, then OP shouldn't tag the question with sed, grep etc, he did it, so I assume the text is what he quoted in question. otherwise, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @KalinBorisov if the question is "how", please check my answer.

Comment: @Kent I mean to separate the result with "|"
`10.1.1.2|host2|http|active`

Comment: @KalinBorisov you meant you got different output from mine? the both ways (grep|xargs and awk) ?

Comment: @Kent, my question is how get that results:
`10.1.1.2|host2|http|active` is it possible and how to change your sintax?

Comment: @Kent another question, is it possible when I get that values to add some tag before and after them for example: 
`<p>10.1.1.2</p> <b>host2</b> <tr><td>http</td></tr> <br>active`

Comment: @KalinBorisov why didn't you put those requirements in your question when you posted it? the answer is yes, it is possible. if you find answer to solve your current problem, please close it.

Comment: @Kent I just wondering what are the possibility that's it, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 6):

First, input string should be valid JSON, so array elements need to be inside `[]` and last array element should not have trailing comma.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;
my $s = q(
  [
    {"ipaddr":"10.1.1.2","hostname":"host2","role":"http","status":"active"},
    {"ipaddr":"10.1.1.3","hostname":"host3","role":"sql","status":"active"},
    {"ipaddr":"10.1.1.4","hostname":"host4","role":"quad","status":"active"}
  ]
);

my $aref = decode_json($s);
my @k = qw( ipaddr hostname role status );

print "@$_{@k}\n" for @$aref;

# or
local $" = "|";
print "@$_{@k}\n" for @$aref;
```

output

```
10.1.1.2 host2 http active
10.1.1.3 host3 sql active
10.1.1.4 host4 quad active
```

---

```
10.1.1.2|host2|http|active
10.1.1.3|host3|sql|active
10.1.1.4|host4|quad|active
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `from_json` returns a reference to a hash, you can take a "slice" of that hash  and return a list of values in those fields. For each line that you present here, you could do the following:

```
s/,\s*$//;join( "\t", @{ from_json( $line) }{ qw<ipaddr hostname role status> } );
```

Of course this would have to be done importing the [`JSON`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON) library. So on the command line it would look like this:

```
perl -MJSON -ne 's/,\s*$//;print join( "\t", @{ from_json($_) }{ qw<ipaddr hostname role status> } ), "\n"'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F\" '{print $4,$8,$12,$16}' file
10.1.1.2 host2 http active
10.1.1.3 host3 sql active
10.1.1.4 host4 quad active
```

Other variation

```
awk -F\" '{for (i=4;i<=16;i+=4) printf "%s ",$i;print ""}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lne 'push @a,/:\"([^\"]*)\"/g;print "@a";undef @a' your_file
```

Tested:

```
> cat temp
{"ipaddr":"10.1.1.2","hostname":"host2","role":"http","status":"active"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.1.3","hostname":"host3","role":"sql","status":"active"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.1.4","hostname":"host4","role":"quad","status":"active"},
> perl -lne 'push @a,/:\"([^\"]*)\"/g;print "@a";undef @a' temp
10.1.1.2 host2 http active
10.1.1.3 host3 sql active
10.1.1.4 host4 quad active
>
```